# How do I read the url parameters from a ZendFramework Controller

Tags: zend-framework, zend-controller

I have a ZendFramework controller whose view forms a framework similar to this:

> http://foo.com/#/controler/someaction/state/city/address/

The action looks like this:

```
public function someactionAction()
{
    $this->view->someaction = App_Model_WebService_Menu::getInstance()->getRows(array(
        'address' => '1600 Pennsylvania Ave',
        'returnRecordsLimit' => 1,
    ));    
}
```

Is there a way where I can access state, city and address as parameters?

Answer (score 0):

From [`Zend_Controller_Request` documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.request.html#zend.controller.request.http.dataacess)

```
$state   = $this->getRequest()->getParam('state');
$city    = $this->getRequest()->getParam('city');
$address = $this->getRequest()->getParam('address');
```

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the URL fragment part which I assume is reliant on some JavaScript configuration, that looks like it would be part of a custom route, ie

```
:controller/:action/:state/:city/:address
```

You will have to look into the route definition to discover the actual parameter names, after which you simply use (from your controller)

```
$state = $this->_getParam('state-param-name');
```